# Why does this jquery .css line not work within 2 functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this simple jquery .css statement does not activate within two functions, am I doing something wrong?

javascript:

```
function updateAllCSS(element, property, value) {

    function updateThemeCreatorCSS(element, property, value) {
        $(element).css(property, value)
    }
    updateThemeCreatorCSS(element, property, value)
}
}

updateAllCSS('h1', 'backgroundColor', '#f00')
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Test header</h1>
```

Comment: You need to quote your strings when you call `updateAllCSS`.

Comment: sorry that was just in this rewrite: it still doesnt work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
function updateAllCSS(element, property, value) {
    function updateThemeCreatorCSS(element, property, value) {
        $(element).css(property, value)
    }
    updateThemeCreatorCSS(element, property, value);
}

updateAllCSS('h1', 'background-color', '#f00');
```

There was an extra `}` and the parameters being passed to `updateAllCSS` needed to have `'`quotes`'`.

Comment: It works as `backgroundColor` as well.  Hyphenated CSS properties can be referenced as camelCase in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You had an extra `}` and you should quote your parameters.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pnA55/1)**

```
function updateAllCSS(element, property, value) {
    function updateThemeCreatorCSS(element, property, value) {
        $(element).css(property, value)
    }
    updateThemeCreatorCSS(element, property, value);
}
updateAllCSS('h1', 'backgroundColor', '#f00');​
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you have that nested function.  Here's a Fiddle of it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/cbbdW/